# Scheduled sleep and wake-up using Windows 10 Task Scheduler not work using C#

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I use the Task Scheduler on Windows 10 to set up scheduled hibernate and wake-up.
During the specified hibernate time, the computer successfully enters the hibernate state. However, at the specified wake-up time, the computer's screen lights up for a short period and then goes black again (I believe it enters sleep mode at this point). At this point, I need to press a key or move the mouse to make the screen light up again. How can I directly wake up and display the Windows interface after executing the task schedule without requiring any keyboard or mouse operations?

```
 public static void SetDailyHibernate Task(bool enable, TimeSpan sleepTime)
 {
     using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
     {
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("DailySleepTask", false);

         if (enable)
         {
             DailyTrigger sleepTrigger = new DailyTrigger();
             sleepTrigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today.Add(sleepTime);
             sleepTrigger.DaysInterval = 1;

             ExecAction sleepAction = new ExecAction("shutdown", "-h", null);

             TaskDefinition sleepTask = ts.NewTask();
             sleepTask.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Daily Sleep Task";
             sleepTask.Principal.UserId = "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM";
             sleepTask.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;
             sleepTask.Triggers.Add(sleepTrigger);
             sleepTask.Actions.Add(sleepAction);

             ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("DailySleepTask", sleepTask);           
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("disable dailySleep");            
         }
     }
 }

 public static void SetDailyWakeTask(bool enable, TimeSpan wakeTime)
 {
     using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
     {
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("DailyWakeTask", false);

         if (enable)
         {
             DailyTrigger wakeTrigger = new DailyTrigger();
             wakeTrigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today.Add(wakeTime);
             wakeTrigger.DaysInterval = 1;

             ExecAction wakeAction = new ExecAction("powercfg", "/h on", null);

             TaskDefinition wakeTask = ts.NewTask();
             wakeTask.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Daily Wake Task";
             wakeTask.Principal.UserId = "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM";
             wakeTask.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;
             wakeTask.Settings.WakeToRun = true;
             wakeTask.Triggers.Add(wakeTrigger);
             wakeTask.Actions.Add(wakeAction);

             ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("DailyWakeTask", wakeTask);
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("disable dailyWakeTask");
         }
     }
 }
```

I have attempted to disable sleep, disabled the "Require a password when the computer wakes" setting, Power Settings -> Sleep -> Allow Wake Timers setting, and set to "Run with highest privileges," but none of these have worked. I also tried using a script simulating keyboard and mouse movements as the scheduled task, but the task does not take effect; it only executes after I manually move the keyboard or mouse to wake up the system from sleep.